# Why bottom navigation bar overlay on app screen layout?

Tags: android, camera

Bottom navigation bar overlay on app layout. I don't want to hide navigation bar. [bottom navigation bar overlay on app  layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ePMi.jpg)

Comment: Kindly show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout as parent layout and use this property

```
android:layout_below="@+id/aboveElement"
```

for example-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activity.HomeScreen">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLinearHome"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_navigation" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />
</RelativeLayout>
```